# How to stop playing video if user switches to another HDMI?

Tags: java, android, android-tv

How to stop playing video if user switches to another HDMI? for android tv

for example, I watch a video, and then I turn off the TV, but the TV box is on and my application should pause the video

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to monitor the HDMI plug-out event when playback.

you can ask chipset manufacture for checking this function can be supported or not

As I know RTK1319 ATV platform can support this function.

maybe this can help you.